# awaiting resources data from api on every language change before using i18n.use(LanguageDetector).init()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next

Sorry if this question has been answered before but I couldn't find a solution to my problem. I am a beginner in react kind of.

Basically, all I want to do is that the language resources I have comes from an api not static. so i need to wait for the api request to finsih before initializing i18n.

I played around with async / await and it works. but I need to do this every time language changes and I can't seem to do it right.

Notice that I keep on calling i18n.use(LanguageDetector).init()

so basically I made 3 functions like this (translateEn, translateAr, translateTr) and I call them every time language changes and it works but it's silly to do it this way.

again sorry I feel this should be too easy and I am making it more complicated than it should be. I am sure there is a much better way to doing this.

```
//i18n.js

import i18n from "i18next";
import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";
import API from './apis/API'

i18n.use(LanguageDetector).init({
  // we init with resources
  resources: {
    en: {
      translations: {},
    ar: {
      translations: {}
    },
    tr: {
      translations: {}
    }
  },
  fallbackLng: "en",
  debug: true,
  ns: ["translations"],
  defaultNS: "translations",
  keySeparator: false,
  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false, 
    formatSeparator: ","
  },
  react: {
    wait: true
  }
});

const en = {translations: {}}
const translateEn = async () => {
  const getEnLang = await API.get('translate/interface?language=1')
  getEnLang.data.data.forEach( i => {
    en.translations[i.key] = i.value
  })
  i18n.use(LanguageDetector).init({
    resources: {
      en,
      ar: {
        translations: {}
      },
      tr: {translations: {}}
    }
  })

}

translateEn()

export {i18n,translateEn}
```

Comment: Although I'm struggling to load resources async and have them picked up, I must note that you should maybe be using `i18n.addResources(resources)` not `i18n.use()` when you load in the new languages. Although I have yet to successfully get that to work, I just know that you shouldn't call `init()` twice.

Comment: Have you tried using i18next backend options to retrieve translations from a backend?
Besides that: You should `init`  i18n only once.